# How can I imitate R's rasterImage function in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, rasterizing

As the question states is there a method that does what [rasterImage function](http://rfunction.com/archives/2666) does in R?

Comment: What's the specific usecase?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: @Adarsh Chavakula I'm trying to plot  first eigenvector as 25 by 25 image. Basically I created patch matrix but I'd like to point its density points for example if darker in the center explains better variance at that location.R code is like this : plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),t='n')
rasterImage((patch_eigenvector2-min(patch_eigenvector2))/(max(patch_eigenvector2)-min(patch_eigenvector2)),0,0,1,1,interpolate=FALSE)

Comment: Matplotlib is the de-facto tool for plotting in Python. Seaborn, built on top of it is also pretty good. I'd recommend using the heatmap in seaborn - https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec